# GCC capturing of `this` in lambda

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda

I have a code like:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional> 

class test {
public:
    void Do() {
        this->test_fun();
    }

    void Init() {
        this->number = 1008;
        this->test_fun = [this] {
            this->test_fun = nullptr;
            printf("number %d\n", this->number); //gcc crash here, this == nullptr
        };

    }

public:
    std::function<void()> test_fun;
    int number = 0;
};


int main() {
    test t;
    t.Init();
    t.Do();

    return 0;
}
```

It can run on MSVC2013, but crash on gcc on the line: `printf("number %d\n", this->number);`

What am I doing wrong?

GCC Version: gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15) (GCC)

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d25adfac83a62b63).

Comment: Works for me, with gcc 6.1.1

Comment: my version is : gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15) (GCC) .

Comment: That lambda is destoyed at the `this->test_fun = nullptr;` line, I guess it's UB

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That line is inside the lambda function, which isn't called until `Do`.

Comment: It seems to be a gcc 4.X issue: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FTyQmPugvG29WIA7 Works with gcc >= 5 as far as I can tell.

Comment: nullptr causes undefined behavior here, that is why it sometimes works and sometime does not

Comment: @molbdnilo so? `Do` is eventually invoked. can you proove that `this` is not captured as a data member of the closure type, and once `this->number` is accessed, it's not referring to an already invalidated memory area?

Comment: thanks all, I will upgrade my gcc version, and try again :)

Comment: @ejkoy compiler update is not a remedy for UB, your code can be translated to e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c26255ae8160ab74

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Oh yeah, now I get it. Got confused by the name "this" and forgot about the indirection through the closure.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks a lot! I see what happened now.

Comment: That specific sample works with GCC-9, but I can still trigger the undefined behavior with slightly more complicated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code introduces undefined behavior, due to the the self destruction of the lambda with

```
this->test_fun = nullptr;
```

This example should be equivalent:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

class test {
public:
    struct Lambda {
        test* this_ptr;
        Lambda(test* this_ptr) : this_ptr(this_ptr) {}
        ~Lambda() {
            this_ptr = nullptr;
        }
        void operator () () {
            printf("this_ptr %p\n", (void*)this_ptr);
            // self destruction
            this_ptr->test_fun = nullptr;
            // undefined behavior starts here ...
            printf("this_ptr %p\n", (void*)this_ptr);
            printf("number %d\n", this_ptr->number);
        }
    };

    void Do() {
        assert(this->test_fun.get());
        (*this->test_fun)();
    }

    void Init() {
        this->number = 1008;
        this->test_fun = std::make_unique<Lambda>(this);
    }

public:
    std::unique_ptr<Lambda> test_fun;
    int number = 0;
};


int main() {
    test t;
    t.Init();
    t.Do();

    return 0;
}
```